# SQL Server : dynamically change database name in SELECT statement based on a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks mostly like:

```
 DECLARE @Vendor varchar (50)
--SET @Vendor = 55 --One vendor
--Set @Vendor = 234 --Another vendor
--SET @Vendor = 123 --Another vendor

SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;

SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;
```

I cycle through the list of vendor numbers that are commented out by uncommenting whichever vendor I need info on.  (It's a much longer list than just the 3 listed above.  This lets me use one query for all vendors, and without having to memorize the vendor numbers).

The only annoyance is that there are a bunch of different databases on the same server, and depending on the vendor, I need to manually select the correct db from the drop down.

Ideally, I would like to write some kind of IF statement that will either SET the database name, or replace the "[dbo]" in front of the table name, depending on what the vendor number is that gets set above.

So like,

```
IF @Vendor = 55 
   SET @database = "Vendor1DB", 
ELSE IF @Vendor = 234 
   SET @database = "Vendor2DB" (and so on)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like a strange design. But maybe it'll help you, if you created a view in all databases `UNION`ing all vendors from all database and just query the view. Of course you could also use dynamic SQL or a lot of `IF`s etc.. But such a view seems less messy.

Comment: What is the data type of vendor_key? I see the variable is declared as varchar(50) yet the literals look to be integers.

Comment: They are integers.  Truthfully, I'm still learning, so I just tried declaring it as something generic and it worked, so I didn't think more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is one method:

```
DECLARE @vendor int = 55;
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname;
DECLARE @SqlScript nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @DatabaseName =
    CASE @vendor
        WHEN 55 THEN  'OneVendor'
        WHEN 234 THEN 'AnotherVendor'
        WHEN 123 THEN 'YetAnotherVendor'
    END;
IF @DatabaseName IS NULL
    RAISERROR( 'Unknown vendor (%d) specified', 16, 1, @vendor);
SET @SqlScript = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;

SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;
';
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
      @SqlScript
    , N'@Vendor varchar(50)'
    , @vendor=@vendor;
GO
```

Another is with a SQLCMD script run from SSMS in SQLCMD mode (Query-->SQLCMD Mode). Unfortunately, there's not a easy way to set SQLCMD variables dynamically. The example below uses T-SQL to generate and executed the needed SETVAR command using [the technique described here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117676/sql-server-sqlcmd-setvar-depending-of-selected-database).

```
--redirect STDOUT to file
:out d:\temp\UseStatement.sql
GO

--generate file with :SETVAR DatabaseName
DECLARE @vendor int = 55;
DECLARE @SetVarCommand nvarchar(200);
SELECT @SetVarCommand =
    CASE @vendor
        WHEN 55 THEN  ':SETVAR DatabaseName OneVendor;'
        WHEN 234 THEN ':SETVAR DatabaseName AnotherVendor;'
        WHEN 123 THEN ':SETVAR DatabaseName YetAnotherVendor;'
    END;
IF @SetVarCommand IS NULL
    RAISERROR( 'Unknown vendor (%d) specified', 16, 1, @vendor);
PRINT @SetVarCommand;
GO

--redirect STDOUT to default
:out stdout
GO

--execute SETVAR script for DatabaseName
:r d:\temp\UseStatement.sql
GO
--specify $(DatabaseName) in your sql script where the database name is needed
USE $(DatabaseName);
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;

SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
  AND create_date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
ORDER BY column1;
GO
```

Comment: Using the dynamic SQL method you described first, all I would need to do to change the vendor is change that top line, right?  (So I could have multiple lines of DECLARE @vendor int = ## commented out and just uncomment whichever one I wanted to switch to?)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, is there any reason that I would want to use SQLCMD instead of Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @DebbiePiquelle, with either script, the only change is the vendor value. The only issue with the dynamic SQL script is you'll need to double up single quotes within your actual script, if needed. BTW, it's unclear if vendor is an int or varchar since you declare it as varchar yet use integer literals. The definition should match the actual column type.